# Making blank rows in a php array from MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

My query returns two days, say the 10th and the 11th, both just integers.  I want to create an array for August with 31 rows, with blank data on days that do not exist in the database, and only data for the 10th and 11th.  If I do something like:

```
$daysinmonth = array( "January"=>31, "February"=>29, "March"=>31, "April"=>30, "May"=>31, "June"=>30, "July"=>31, "August"=>31, "September"=>30, "October"=>31, "November"=>30, "December"=>31 );

$days = $daysinmonth[$month] - 1;

$i=0;
echo $numB;
while ($i<$days) {
 $a = $i + 1;
 $day = mysql_query($resultB,$i,"day"); 
 if ( $a==$day ) { 
  $date[$i] = $a;
  $movies[$i] = mysql_result($resultB,$i,"movies");
  $shows[$i] = mysql_result($resultB,$i,"shows");
  $music[$i] = mysql_result($resultB,$i,"music"); }
 else { $date[$i] = $a;
  $movies[$i] = "";
  $shows[$i] = "";
  $music[$i] = ""; } $i++; }
```

Which throws a MySQL error, of course, because there are only two rows of data.  I don't even know what to ask because I don't understand most of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//select the data from your table
$sql = "SELECT day, movies, shows, music FROM something WHERE something";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  //put it in an array keyed by the date
  $data[$row['day']] = $row;
}

//calculate the first and last day of the month's timestamps
$first_day_of_this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));
$last_day_of_this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') + 1, 0, date('Y'));

//loop over every day of this month
for ($i = $first_day_of_this_month; $i <= $last_day_of_this_month; $i = strtotime('+1 day', $i)) {
  $date = date('Y-m-d', $i);
  echo 'Date ' . $date . ':';
  if (isset($data[$date])) { //a row existed for this date
    echo $data[$date]['movies'] . ' movies, ' . $data[$date]['shows'] . ' shows,' . $data[$date]['music'] . ' music';
  }
  echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for the help.  That took care of it!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
//use default features of php instead of your own $daysinmonth
$from = new DateTime('2011-01-31');
$to = new DateTime('2011-02-28');
date_modify($from, '-1 day');
$emtpy_data = array();
//fill empty data for dates
while ($from->format('Y-m-d') != $to->format('Y-m-d')) {
    date_modify($from, '+1 day');
    $empty_data[$from->format('Y-m-d')] = array();
}
//then select all data you need from db and append or overwrite empty data with db rows
$q = mysql_query("select something from table where date='$some_date'");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc) {
    $empty_data[$some_date] = $r;
}
```